# Multi level Nested TreeView with Dynamic Binding in WPF

Tags: wpf, treeview, dynamic-binding

I am trying to create an application in which i require to display employees and their departments in the treeview kind of structure as below :

- Employee1

  - Department

    - Dept1
    - Dept2
- Employee2

  - Department

    - Dept3
    - Dept4

how could i do this with WPF ?

Answer (score 2):

The correct way to do this is to use a [`HierarchicalDataTemplate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.hierarchicaldatatemplate%28vs.85%29.aspx). The most basic one I can imagine is the following:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate
            x:Key="RecursiveData" DataType="TreeViewItem" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </UserControl.Resources>
```

Which can be used in the XAML as follows:

```
<TreeView ItemTemplate="{StaticResource RecursiveData}" />
```

Of course you can customize the template at will with styles and subcomponents.

Note that the `ItemSource` of your TreeView needs to actually provide nested `TreeViewItem`s where each TreeViewItem contains it's subitems in `Items`.

Answer (score 0):

If you've structure like this:

```
public ObservableCollection<ChartOfAccount> ChartOfAccounts { get; set; }

public class ChartOfAccount
{
    public Book Book { get; set; }
    public List<LedgerHierarchy> ControlLedgers { get; set; }
}

public class LedgerHierarchy
{
    public ControlLedger ControlLedger { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<Ledger> Ledgers { get; set; }
}
```

you could bind directly in `TreeView` like this:

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding ChartOfAccounts}"
          BorderThickness="0"
          ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
          ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource treeStyle}">
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding ControlLedgers}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Book.Name}"/>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Ledgers}">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ControlLedger.Name}"/>
                    <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

instead of creating `HierarchicalDataTemplate` in `Control.Resource`.